# Footer Image Will Not Size Correctly

Tags: java, android, swipe, android-adapter, fill

I have a footer image which does not seem to size correctly: it is cut off on every side and appears to overlap with other images (assigned to the PagerAdapter as well).

How can this be avoided?

Screenshot:

[image]

### JAVA SNIPPET:

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] mImages = new int[] {
            R.drawable.classical_up_btn,
            R.drawable.country_up_btn,
            R.drawable.dance_up_btn,
            R.drawable.hiphop_up_btn
    };

    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }

    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = Home.this;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding =context.getResources().  
                getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0); 
        return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
 }
}
```

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_drawer"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/darkgrey"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#AAFFFFFF" >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/groupScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
                    android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Throw &apos;Em Up"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn1"
                        android:layout_width="27dp"
                        android:layout_height="27dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                        android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="by DJ Generic  |"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="  100,000 views"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp" >
                </View>

                <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                    android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dip"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Bulls On Parade"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                        android:layout_width="27dp"
                        android:layout_height="27dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                        android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="by Rage Against The Machine  |"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="  100,000 views"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp" >
                </View>

                <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                    android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dip"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Isaac Daniel on CNN with Anderson Cooper"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                        android:layout_width="27dp"
                        android:layout_height="27dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                        android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="by idconex  |"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2a"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="  100,000 views"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp" >
                </View>

                <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                    android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dip"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Bulls On Parade"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                        android:layout_width="27dp"
                        android:layout_height="27dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                        android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="by Rage Against The Machine  |"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="  100,000 views"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="25dp" >
                </View>

                <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView
                    android:id="@+id/youtubethumbnailview4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dip"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1a"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="Isaac Daniel on CNN with Anderson Cooper"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/fav_up_btn"
                        android:layout_width="27dp"
                        android:layout_height="27dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1a"
                        android:background="@drawable/fav_up_btn1"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp"
                        android:paddingTop="5dp" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2a"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3a"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="by idconex  |"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:textColor="@color/lightgrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3a"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:text="  100,000 views"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="75dp" >
                    </View>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dip"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/darkgrey" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:src="@drawable/home_up_btn" />

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/groupScrollView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/darkgrey" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@color/darkgrey"
                    android:src="@drawable/selstation_up_btn" />
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:src="@drawable/scroll_lt_arrow" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/scroll_rt_arrow" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/view_pager"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: try scaletype FIT_XY  instead of CENTER on your imageview

Comment: I tried it: it did not resolve the issue... (I'll post my XML for further clarification/insight)

Comment: did you try to mess around with imageView.setLayoutParams() and keep scaletype.FIT_XY

Answer (score 0):

If you use CENTER, FIT_XY, or any of the other similar parameters you need to specify an exact size for the View rather than using `match_parent`, `fill_parent`, etc.  If you do want to use the parent layout parameters then you will need to specify the image in java source with

```
Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(drawable_id);
imageView.setImageBitmap(((BitmapDrawable) d).getBitmap());
```

Comment: I'm getting an error stating "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) from the type ImageView"

Comment: I tried using: 

Bitmap d = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
        R.drawable.selstation_up_btn);
imageView.setImageDrawable(d);  


and it compiles but it still does not resize the image correctly.